# Select data with ZonedDateTime

Tags: java, timestamp, postgresql-9.1, zoneddatetime

I have object

```
...
@CreatedDate
@Column(name = "created_date", nullable = false)
@JsonIgnore
private ZonedDateTime createdDate = ZonedDateTime.now();
...
```

table - postgeSQL

```
 create table inventory_request
 (...
   created_date timestamp,
   .....
 );
```

I need to select objects with databases between dates `ZonedDateTime.now()` and last year - `ZonedDateTime.now().minusMonths(12)`

my JPA repository

```
List<Inventory> findByCreatedDateBetween(ZonedDateTime now, ZonedDateTime end);
```

after execute i have only empty array, but values is present in database

I try use TimeStamp - `'java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter value [2018-11-20 14:44:23.528] did not match expected type [java.time.ZonedDateTime (n/a)]'`

How is fix it? How to get the necessary data please help? Thanks!

Comment: Have you accidentally reversed the two arguments? I believe they should be in the order `(oneYearAgo, now)`. Depending on what your method expects, of course.

Comment: I'm an stupid!! )))  Thanks!!!! Very thanks!